# Checking if the user is working at a given time in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
$workStart = $point->start; // return 01:05:00
$workEnd = $point->finish; // return 05:30:00

$timeNow = Carbon::now()->format('H:i'); // return 12:30:34

if (.....){
  echo "user work";
} else {
  echo "user NOT work";
}
```

How can I check if the user is working at the moment or not?

Comment: is it 12 hours format or 24 hours format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare our current time lies in given format by comparing the current time with start and end time.

```
$workStart = $point->start; // return 01:05:00
$workEnd = $point->finish; // return 05:30:00

$timeNow = Carbon::now()->format('H:i'); // return 12:30:34

if (strtotime($workStart) < strtotime($timeNow) && strtotime($workEnd) > strtotime($timeNow)){
  echo "user work";
} else {
  echo "user NOT work";
}
```

Comment: A clear solution may be to use Carbon's `between` function:
`$isWorking = Carbon::now()->between( new Carbon( $workStart ), new Carbon( $workEnd ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply logic as below:

UPDATE: The value fetched from a database needs to be converted from English textual date-time to a UNIX timestamp.

```
if(strtotime($workStart) < strtotime($workEnd)) {
  if ((strtotime($timeNow) > strtotime($workStart)) && (strtotime($workEnd) > strtotime($timeNow))){
    echo "user work";
  } else {
    echo "user NOT work";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's not working :( The script always returns an incorrect result

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [documentation for the Carbon date class](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)?  There is a between function built in for this.

It makes nice, human readable code:

```
$workStart = Carbon::createFromTimeString($point->start);
$workEnd =Carbon::createFromTimeString($point->finish);


if (Carbon::now()->between($workStart,$workEnd){
  echo "user work";
} else {
  echo "user NOT work";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. it checks based on am/pm. remember to `use Carbon\carbon;`

```
public function Checkwork()
   {
   $meeting = Carbon::now();
   $tim=$meeting->format('H:i:s');

   $workStart = '01:05:00'; // return 01:05:00 
   $workEnd = '05:30:00'; // return 05:30:00 


   if(($tim<$workStart)&&($tim>$workEnd)){

    dd('working');
  // dd($tim);

   }
   else{
    //dd($tim);
    dd('not working');
   }

 }
```

Comment: i also believe that the value of $workStart and $workEnd inputted from the view